# How to split text into chunks minimizing the solution?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, split, computer-science

**OVERVIEW**

I got a set of possible valid chunks I can use to split a text (if possible).

How can i split a given text using these chunks such as the result will be optimized (minimized) in terms of the number of resulting chunks?

**TEST SUITE**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    import sys

    random.seed(1)

    # 1) Testing robustness
    examples = []
    sys.stdout.write("Testing correctness...")
    N = 50
    large_number = "3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481"
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(i):
            choices = random.sample(range(i), j)
            examples.append((choices, large_number))

    for (choices, large_number) in examples:
        get_it_done(choices, large_number)
    sys.stdout.write("OK")

    # 2) Testing correctness
    examples = [
        # Example1 ->
        # Solution ['012345678910203040506070', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']
        (
            [
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900",
                "012345678910203040506070"
            ],
            "0123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        # Example2
        ## Solution ['100']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "100"
        ),
        # Example3
        ## Solution ['101234567891020304050', '6070809010020030040050', '0600700800900']
        (
            [
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "012345678910203040506070",
                "101234567891020304050",
                "6070809010020030040050",
                "0600700800900"
            ],
            "10123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        # Example4
        ### Solution ['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
        (
            [
                "12", "34", "56", "78", "90",
                "890",
            ],
            "1234567890"
        ),
        # Example5
        ## Solution ['12', '34']
        (
            [
                "1", "2", "3",
                "12", "23", "34"
            ],
            "1234"
        ),
        # Example6
        ## Solution ['100', '10']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "10010"
        )
    ]

    score = 0
    for (choices, large_number) in examples:
        res = get_it_done(choices, large_number)
        flag = "".join(res) == large_number
        print("{0}\n{1}\n{2} --> {3}".format(
            large_number, "".join(res), res, flag))
        print('-' * 80)
        score += flag

    print(
        "Score: {0}/{1} = {2:.2f}%".format(score, len(examples), score / len(examples) * 100))

    # 3) TODO: Testing optimization, it should provide (if possible)
    #          minimal cases
```

**QUESTION**

How could I solve this problem on python without using a brute-force approach?

Comment: The naive solution seems to be starting with the largest of your chunks and looking for it in the string.  If you find it, split the string into the two substrings on either side and then recursively consider those strings.

Comment: Was my first thought as well, but I am unsure if that is guaranteed to produce the optimal solution. It might be possible to replace a part with 1 long and 2 short or 2 medium sized chunks. In this case, this algorithm would fail to produce the optimal solution.

Comment: The greedy algorithm will usually create a good solution, if not the optimum solution. The nice thing is that it's simple to implement. You can probably get an optimum solution with dynamic programming, but it could take some time. The optimum solution might in fact be computationally hard.

Comment: By chunks you mean substrings or tokens? My first thought was text compression (Huffman codes) if you are allowed to make your own (prefix-free) tokens, but that does not really match the question. I concur on dynamic programming being likely, but that's a pretty broad topic.

Comment: The first comment, from @PatrickHaugh gave the basic idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, the implementation is a bit hacky. But I think it always returns the optimal answer. (Did not proove, though.) It is a fast and complete implementation in python and returns the correct answers for all proposed use cases.

The algorithm is recursive and works as follows:

1. start at the beginning of the text.
2. find matching chunks that can be used as the first chunk.
3. for each matching chunk, recursively start at step 1. with the rest of the text (i.e. the chunk removed from the start) and collect the solutions
4. return the shortest of the collected solutions

When the algorithm is done, all possible paths (and the not possible ones, i.e. no match at the end) should have been traversed exactly once.

To perform step 2 efficiently, I build a patricia tree for the choices so the possible chunks matching the beginning of the text can be looked up quickly.

```
def get_seq_in_tree(tree, choice):
    if type(tree)!=dict:
        if choice == tree:
            return [choice]
        return []
    for i in range(1, len(choice)+1):
        if choice[:i] in tree:
            return [choice[:i]] + get_seq_in_tree(tree[choice[:i]], choice[i:])
    return []

def seq_can_end_here(tree, seq):
    res = []
    last = tree
    for e, c in enumerate(seq):
        if '' in last[c]:
            res.append(e+1)
        last = last[c]
    return res

def build_tree(choices):
    tree = {}
    choices = sorted(choices)
    for choice in choices:
        last = tree
        for c in choice:
            if c not in last:
                last[c] = {}
            last = last[c]
        last['']=None
    return tree

solution_cache = {}
ncalls = 0

def solve(tree, number):
    global solution_cache
    global ncalls
    ncalls +=1

    # take every path only once
    if number in solution_cache: 
        return solution_cache[number]

    solutions = []
    seq =  get_seq_in_tree(tree, number)
    endings = seq_can_end_here(tree, seq)
    for i in reversed(endings):
        current_solution = []
        current_solution.append(number[:i])
        if i == len(number):
            solutions.append(current_solution)
        else:
            next_solution = solve(tree, number[i:])
            if next_solution:
                solutions.append(current_solution + next_solution)
    if not solutions:
        return None

    shortest_solution = sorted([(len(solution), solution) for solution in solutions])[0][1]

    solution_cache[number] = shortest_solution
    return shortest_solution

def get_it_done(choices, number):
    tree = build_tree(choices)
    solution = solve(tree, number)
    return solution


if __name__ == "__main__":

    examples = [
        # Example1 ->
        # Solution ['012345678910203040506070', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']
        (
            [
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900",
                "012345678910203040506070"
            ],
            "0123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ## Example2
        ## Solution ['100']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "100"
        ),
        ## Example3
        ## Solution ['101234567891020304050', '6070809010020030040050', '0600700800900']
        (
            [
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "012345678910203040506070",
                "101234567891020304050",
                "6070809010020030040050",
                "0600700800900"
            ],
            "10123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ### Example4
        ### Solution ['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
        (
            [
                "12", "34", "56", "78", "90",
                "890",
            ],
            "1234567890"
        ),
        ## Example5
        ## Solution ['12', '34']
        (
            [
                "1", "2", "3",
                "12", "23", "34"
            ],
            "1234"
        ),
        # Example6
        ## Solution ['100', '10']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "10010"
        )
    ]

    score = 0
    for (choices, large_number) in examples:
        res = get_it_done(choices, large_number)
        flag = "".join(res) == large_number
        print("{0}\n{1}\n{2} --> {3}".format(
            large_number, "".join(res), res, flag))
        print('-' * 80)
        score += flag

    print("Score: {0}/{1} = {2:.2f}%".format(score, len(examples), score / len(examples) * 100))
```

I guess the complexity is something like O(L * N * log(C)) where L is the length of the text, N is the size of the vocabulary and C is the number of choices.

**EDIT:** Included the missing test case.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the remark. No idea how the 6th test could get deleted... But it works as expected on the last case, too.

Answer (score 7):

Using dynamic programming, you can construct a list `(l0, l1, l2, ... ln-1)`, where `n` is the number of characters in your input string and `li` is the minimum number of chunks you need to arrive at character `i` of the input string. The overall structure would look as follows:

```
minValues := list with n infinity entries
for i from 0 to n-1
    for every choice c that is a suffix of input[0..i]
        if i - len(c) < 0
            newVal = 1
        else
            newVal = minValues[i - len(c)] + 1
        end if
        if(newVal < minValues[i])
            minValues[i] = newVal
            //optionally record the used chunk
        end if
    next
next
```

The minimum number of chunk for your entire string is then `ln-1`. You can get the actual chunks by tracking back through the list (which requires to record the used chunks).

Retrieving the choices that are suffixes can be sped up using a trie (of the reverse choice strings). The worst case complexity will still be `O(n * c * lc)`, where `n` is the length of the input string, `c` is the number of choices, and `lc` is the maximum length of the choices. However, this complexity will only occur for choices that are nested suffixes (e.g. `0`, `10`, `010`, `0010`...). In this case, the trie will degenerate to a list. In average, the run time should be much less. Under the assumption that the number of retrieved choices from the trie is always a small constant, it is `O(n * lc)` (actually, the `lc` factor is probably also smaller).

Here is an example:

```
choices = ["0","1","10","100"]
text = "10010"

algorithm step    content of minValues
                   0      1       2        3      4
---------------------------------------------------------
initialize        (∞,     ∞ ,     ∞ ,      ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 0, c = "1"    (1 "1", ∞ ,     ∞ ,      ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 1, c = "0"    (1 "1", 2 "0",  ∞ ,      ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 1, c = "10"   (1 "1", 1 "10", ∞ ,      ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 2, c = "0"    (1 "1", 1 "10", 2 "0",   ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 2, c = "100"  (1 "1", 1 "10", 1 "100", ∞ ,    ∞     )
i = 3, c = "1"    (1 "1", 1 "10", 1 "100", 2 "1", ∞     )
i = 4, c = "0"    (1 "1", 1 "10", 1 "100", 2 "1", 3 "0" )
i = 4, c = "10"   (1 "1", 1 "10", 1 "100", 2 "1", 2 "10")
```

Meaning: We can compose the string with 2 chunks. Tracing back gives the chunks in reverse order: "10", "100".

Comment: I'm looking at the case where input[0..i] cannot be composed from the choices, and it seems to be okay. You just ignore the unusable suffix until you get to something that can compose it at a later i. And if the problem is not solvable, we know that by comparing the reconstructed final answer with the input string. Agreed?

Comment: @BPL: An easy implementation (without the trie) would be as follows: For every choice `c` check the following: Is the last char of `c` `=input[i]`, the second last `=input[i-1]` and so on until `c` is consumed completely.

Comment: @Kenny Yes, partial string that cannot be composed stay at `∞`. An easier way to check if the entire string is composable is checking `minValues[n-1]` for `∞`.

Comment: @Nico A string could be not composible somewhere in the middle, but might have composible prefix and suffix. It seems like that would go undetected until the final reconstruction (which will not match the input string). But that still gets the answer, +1

Comment: @BPL: There might be a solution with some modified suffix tree, but I don't have a good idea for that. A suffix tree is also a trie like I suggested for the suffix retrieval. So maybe you could get the two structures together in a clever way. But I don't know.

Comment: @Kenny The `minValues` list states the number of chunks that you need to compose `input[0..i]` (i.e. the prefix up to `i`). Hence, if some entry is not ∞, you know that the according prefix is composable. `minValues[n-1]` corresponds to the prefix up to the last character, i.e. to the entire input string. If this is a valid number, you know that the entire input string can be composed.

Comment: But you only update it for candidates which are a matching suffix. Oh ... I see now. It will leave "no" there, but later catch the previous matches in the lookback on i - len(candidate). So it is easier to detect "unsolvable" than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if start not in graph:
        return None
    shortest = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest


def get_it_done(choices, number):
    mapping = {}
    graph = {} 

    for choice in choices:
        if choice in number:
            _from = number.index(choice)
            _to = _from + len(choice)
            mapping.setdefault((_from, _to), choice)

    items = sorted(mapping.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
    for _range, value in items:
        _from, _to = _range
        graph.setdefault(_from, []).append(_to)
    start = 0
    end = _range[1] #this is hack, works only in python 2.7
    path = find_shortest_path(graph, start, end) 
    ranges = [tuple(path[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(path) - 1)]
    if len(ranges) == 1:
        items = sorted(choices, key=len, reverse=True)
        number_length = len(number) 
        result = ''
        for item in items:
            result += item
            if len(result) == number_length: 
                return result 
    return [mapping[_range] for _range in ranges]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    examples = [
        # Example1 ->
        # Solution ['012345678910203040506070', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']
        (
            [
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900",
                "012345678910203040506070"
            ],
            "0123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ## Example2
        ## Solution ['100']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "100"
        ),
        ## Example3
        ## Solution ['101234567891020304050', '6070809010020030040050', '0600700800900']
        (
            [
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "012345678910203040506070",
                "101234567891020304050",
                "6070809010020030040050",
                "0600700800900"
            ],
            "10123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ### Example4
        ### Solution ['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
        (
            [
                "12", "34", "56", "78", "90",
                "890",
            ],
            "1234567890"
        ),
        ## Example5
        ## Solution ['12', '34']
        (
            [
                "1", "2", "3",
                "12", "23", "34"
            ],
            "1234"
        ),
        # Example6
        ## Solution ['100', '10']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "10010"
        )
    ]

    score = 0
    for (choices, large_number) in examples:
        res = get_it_done(choices, large_number)
        flag = "".join(res) == large_number
        print("{0}\n{1}\n{2} --> {3}".format(
            large_number, "".join(res), res, flag))
        print('-' * 80)
        score += flag

    print(
        "Score: {0}/{1} = {2:.2f}%".format(score, len(examples), score / len(examples) * 100))
```

`get_it_done` function creates at first `mapping`, where keys are occurency ranges of each `choice` in a `number`. Then sorts it by first item in each key of `mapping` dict. Next step is creating `graph`. Then using `find_shortest_path` function, we can find the shortest path to build result in the most optimal way. So at the end we can use `mapping` again, to return `choices` according to their ranges. If there is one range, we have situation when all numbers consists the same two values, so rules are different. We can collect numbers direct from `choices` (sorted descending) until length of the result will be the same as length of a `number`.

Answer (score -3):

```
def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if start not in graph:
        return None
    shortest = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest


def get_it_done(choices, number):
    mapping = {}
    graph = {} 

    for choice in choices:
        if choice in number:
            _from = number.index(choice)
            _to = _from + len(choice)
            mapping.setdefault((_from, _to), choice)

    items = sorted(mapping.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
    for _range, value in items:
        _from, _to = _range
        graph.setdefault(_from, []).append(_to)
    start = 0
    end = _range[1] #this is hack, works only in python 2.7
    path = find_shortest_path(graph, start, end) 
    ranges = [tuple(path[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(path) - 1)]
    if len(ranges) == 1:
        return [mapping[(start, graph[start][-1])]]
    return [mapping[_range] for _range in ranges]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    examples = [
        # Example1 ->
        # Solution ['012345678910203040506070', '80', '90', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']
        (
            [
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900",
                "012345678910203040506070"
            ],
            "0123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ## Example2
        ## Solution ['100']
        (
            ["0", "1", "10", "100"],
            "100"
        ),
        ## Example3
        ## Solution ['101234567891020304050', '6070809010020030040050', '0600700800900']
        (
            [
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
                "012345678910203040506070",
                "101234567891020304050",
                "6070809010020030040050",
                "0600700800900"
            ],
            "10123456789102030405060708090100200300400500600700800900"
        ),
        ### Example4
        ### Solution ['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
        (
            [
                "12", "34", "56", "78", "90",
                "890",
            ],
            "1234567890"
        ),
        ## Example5
        ## Solution ['12', '34']
        (
            [
                "1", "2", "3",
                "12", "23", "34"
            ],
            "1234"
        )
    ]

    for (choices, large_number) in examples:
        res = get_it_done(choices, large_number)
        print("{0}\n{1}\n{2} --> {3}".format(
            large_number, "".join(res), res, "".join(res) == large_number))
        print('-' * 80)
```

Comment: This is a copy 1:1 of original @turkus algorithm, what's the meaning of this?